# Error swiffy in internet explorer 7 and 8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I adapted a flash animation html Swiffy then pass it to adobe edge and turn it into bedside website, works on all browsers but internet explorer 7 and 8 gives script error.

this is the code that fails, put that Object is undefined and asks me to load the script anyway, I give myself loads and everything perfectly. Is there any way to fix it?

```
  <script>

      var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('swiffycontainer'),
                                   swiffyobject);

      stage.start();
    </script>
```

Comment: Is it swiffy defined on loading time? And swiffy object? Can you post some more code to understand the context?

Comment: I could not solve it and choose to make the entire animation again with html5, sorry, thanks for answering.